# Is there something like mklink that actually makes a copy of a file/folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

I need to keep a local folder of a folder on a network drive for when the computer is removed from the network. Is there anything built into windows 10 that I can use to accomplish this? It must be available offline and can't use new software as these particular computers aren't supposed to be altered with new software.

Answer (score -1):

Before you can make files or folders on your network available offline,
you need to make sure the offline files feature is turned on.
Run from the Start Menu the app "Manage offline files" and click
"Enable offline files".

Then, when connected to the network, open File Explorer and select the file or folder,
on the Home tab, click "Easy access" and then choose
"Always available offline".
If successful, a small green sync icon
([image])
will appear in the corner of the file or folder icon.

To work offline even though you have network access,
open the network location that contains the file or folder you've made available offline and on the Home tab, click "Easy access",
and then choose "Work offline".
When you're finished working offline, choose "Work offline" again.
This will sync any changes you've made offline with the file or folder
on the network.